# Python doesn't go automatically to next line when writing to CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to open a source CSV file (`source.csv`) and decompose it into several CSV files according to first column name. I show it with this example:

Content of `source.csv`:

```
2016-11,a
2016-11,b
2016-12,a
2016-12,b
2016-12,c
```

and I expect the program to create two files with `2016-11.csv` and `2016-12.csv` names:

expected content of `2016-11.csv`:

```
2016-11,a
2016-11,b
```

expected content of `2016-12.csv`:

```
2016-12,a
2016-12,b
2016-12,c
```

---

I developed this code:

```
import csv
path1='/home/sourcefilepath/'
path2='/home/targetpath/'
filename='source.csv'

with open(path1+filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        date=row[0]
        with open(path2+date+'.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The problem is it just write the first line of each file and doesn't automatically goes to next line while writing. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: did you mean to use `'a'`  instead of `'w'` maybe? Also opening and closing the file after each write is a bit inefficient, you can open two files at once as well

Comment: you are right, simply change 'w' to 'a' solved the issue! tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting the contents of your file each time you open them with the `w` flag, try instead by grouping your rows with `itertools.groupby`:

```
import csv
import itertools

with open(path1 + filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for date, rows in itertools.groupby(reader, lambda row: row[0]):
        with open(path2 + date + '.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: 'w' or 'a' ? maybe 'a' is the current one

Comment: @Woeitg The added benefit of using `itertools.groupby` is that you dont't have to open and close your file several times, which is slow, and `writerows` is also faster than calling `writerow` several times.

Comment: I guess if the source file is sorted by the first column, then two answers doesn't have much difference in performance.

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the previous files with `'w'`. Besides opening the file and closing at every iteration is not a very good idea.

Why not read all the rows and group them with `itertools.groupby` using the first item in each row (i.e. date) as the grouping criterion. Then write into each file after splitting. The file `name`s will be the key for each group.